# How to change the font color of selected text in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is second attempt at the same question. My original question has been marked as duplicate but it is not, there is not one answer on the Stackoverflow portal that answers my question.

Is it possible to change the color of the selected text in VS Code? Selecting selection/highlight background color is great but it does not always work since different words are colored differently depending on whether they are comments or special words for any given language. I would love to be able to have a uniform approach to how words are colored when they are selected regardless of whether they are special words/comments/code. etc.
[image]

In the above example the highlighted word "off" is not readable in the section where it is part of a comment due to the fact that comments font color is green.

Comment: you can customize any workbench and editor color (TextMateScope), there are a LOT of Questions/Answers about that here at SO

Comment: Perhaps that is the way to do it. I don't really want to change my colors to fit the text highlighting settings,

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, you can only do this if you are using a theme designated as high-contrast, using the `editor.selectionForeground` colour customization point.

For a full list of colour customization points related to highlighting text in VS Code, see [this post of mine](/a/77662761/11107541).

Comment: I've chosen not to close as a duplicate because of related discussion in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/11107541